# Problem burning DVD with some data already on it

Tags: dvd, burning

I have a DVD that has some data on it(about 7 MB). I want to add further data to it but Ubuntu won't allow it. It shows 0 bytes used and 0 bytes available when I go into properties of the DVD and I am not able to burn additional data to it. The error message shown is insufficient disk space. The data on the disk was earlier written using Windows, could that be a problem?

I have about 10 more disks that have negligible data on them and want to use them for storing other data. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If they are **not** DVD +RW(Rewritable) then you wont be able to write anything.
Could you please confirm if that is not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a mutlisession CD/DVD? If i remember correctly, you can not add sessions after the CD/DVD has been finalized. My guess is that you have already finalized the DVD. It is just a wild guess but that might be the issue.

Well, it has been a while since i last burnt something on a CD/DVD we are in the age of the USB-Sticks after all :D